# AWS IoT - CLI Provision a Security Certificate - is it working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, iot

When I use AWS's CLI to get a security certificate for a IoT Thing I enter:

> aws iot​ describe-certificate --certificate-id *myCertificateId*
>   --output text --query certificateDescription.certificatePem > cert.pem

but I get

> usage: aws [options]   [parameters] aws: error:
>   argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are: blah blah blah

However, cert.pem file was created, but it's empty. 
Also the certificate did show up in the AWS IoT console with the correct *myCertificateId*.

Did it work correctly? Is something wrong with the AWS CLI args parameter error handling?

Comment: AWS IoT is still in beta - So, I think something is wrong with the AWS CLI args parameter error handling.

I can download the Certificate ARN and it matches the certificatePem that I have. 

Also I was able to use the Certificate ARN to attach the certificate to my Thing.

Answer (score 7):

There is a somewhat invisible typo in the code on the website, since there is a zero-width space in the command.

```
aws iot&#8203; describe-certificate [...]
```

Just make sure that you delete/retype the beginning of the copy/pasted command line and you'll be just fine! :-)

Comment: they've now fixed the typo!